# handling dynamic pop-up error message in jmeter

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins

I have a Jmeter script for an application for which i get **pop up error message intermittently**. Where as in jmeter we only come to know that flow got terminated by some failure.But we wont come to know the occurrence of Error pop -up message.

My requirement is if we encounter pop up error i want to write to an external file saying that ,the current page got failed due to pop-up error message.
If we can write the error message it's really great. I'm as of now not getting idea to achieve this.
Please can anyone help me in this. or can provide any hint to do R&D.

Thankyou in advance.

Updated the question with screen shot of error message.[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you must get this error response in your jmeter request response.simple answer.Have a regex to extract.

Answer (score 1):

As per [JMeter project main page](http://jmeter.apache.org/):

> JMeter is not a browser, it works at protocol level. As far as web-services and remote services are concerned, JMeter looks like a browser (or rather, multiple browsers); however JMeter does not perform all the actions supported by browsers. In particular, **JMeter does not execute the Javascript found in HTML pages**. Nor does it render the HTML pages as a browser does (it's possible to view the response as HTML etc., but the timings are not included in any samples, and only one sample in one thread is ever displayed at a time).

Looking into your screenshot, it is a form of [JavaScript popup](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_popup.asp), most likely [window.alert](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/alert) so there is no way to detect it via JMeter.

You can add i.e. [Response Assertion](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Response_Assertion) to your test in order to introduce some pass/fail criteria, i.e. if you were in the middle of some transaction when the error occurred it should not finish successfully resulting in missing expected entry in the web page (or database), so you can conditionally fail relevant sampler(s) in this case. See [How to Use JMeter Assertions in Three Easy Steps](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-jmeter-assertions-3-easy-steps) to learn more about the concept.

---

Alternatively you can use [WebDriver Sampler](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/WebDriverSampler/) plugin which provides JMeter integration with [Selenium](http://www.seleniumhq.org/) browser automation framework which drives a real browser, so you will be able to capture this popups and record the page titles/take screenshots, check out [IsAlertPresent()](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/com/thoughtworks/selenium/webdriven/commands/IsAlertPresent.html) class for more information.